# this_ element dynamic variable? Bootstrap4 Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
var Dropdown = function () {

    function Dropdown(element) {
        _classCallCheck(this, Dropdown);
        this._element = element;
        this._addEventListeners();
    }
```

In bootstrap 4's javascript, they call `this._element = element`.

But `_element` is not defined anywhere.  Is this dynamically instantiating variables?

Comment: `function Dropdown(element)`

Comment: note: `element` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's defined. `this._element` is bound to the current function.

Later in the code they need to call `new Dropdown`

```
var d = new Dropdown("element");
console.log(d._element); // "element"
```

Edit : You can find the real example [here](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.js)

Comment: they call it here...? data = new Dropdown(this);

Comment: Yes exactly :) When you call `new` the `this` inside `Dropdown` is bound.